# How do I set up AWS credentials on Media Temple DV

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials, mediatemple

I am having a hard time setting up the credentials for AWS S3 usage via `aws-php-sdk` within Media Temple.

I continue to receive the error: `Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials`

I tried to follow the guide to install the AWS CLI via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html.  I then used the following to set the credentials via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html#configure-cli

... But I get that error still.

I then had a chat with Media Temple support, who created the .aws/credentials file in root, but then the error message changed to:

`Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/.aws/credentials) is not within the allowed path(s)`

MT advised me to not change the basedir settings. They also advised me to simply change where the credentials are read from if possible.

Anyone successfully use AWS credentials on MT?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this with the AWS CLI via SSH was like beating my head against a brick wall on Media Temple.

I then tried to set the credentials via environment variables, but that was a no-go.

I then got the idea to put the credentials file within a directory that PHP could access.  However, I had to set the location where `aws-php-sdk` would look for it.  I found the environment variable within some documentation and tried to set the variable via php's `setenv()` function.  No dice.

I then searched the `aws-php-sdk` for the initial error I was seeing, backtracked until I could find where the credentials file location was being set.  Turns out the documentation was wrong and the correct environment variable name was `HOME`.

In the end, all that was needed was to set `HOME` prior to using AWS.  Easy enough, but should have been 100x easier to figure out.  Something along these lines:

```
// Set environment variable for credentials location
putenv('HOME=../');

// Set bucket name
$this->bucket = $bucket;

// Create an S3Client
$this->s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'profile' => $this->profile,
    'version' => $this->version,
    'region'  => $this->region
]);
```